# onPause() without intent , onResume() without onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onpause

I'm building an app that plays music on the background with service. The music is muted when the user is not in the app and unmuted when he is back. I used the `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods to do this.

The problem is - every time the user enters a new activity, the music pauses for a second and then resumes, because for a second the current activity is paused. 
another problem - for the first run of the activity, the `onResume()` and `onCreate()` both works, which makes my service stops from the `onResume()` without it even being created from the `onCreate()` (which makes the app shut down).
is there a way to use `onPause()` without the intent part (or another similar way?)

is there a way to use `onCreate()` without to `onResume()` on the first run?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    counter++;

    if (counter==1) {
        alliesSPEditor.putBoolean("isAllies", true);
        alliesSPEditor.commit();
        startService(new Intent(this,MusicService.class));
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MusicService.getMP().mute();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (counter!=1) //because the counter is still 1, the app won't shut down this way but it will not unmute the music.
    MusicService.getMP().unMute();

}
```

Comment: [No](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

`onResume()` is always called after `onCreate()` before the activity starts running

See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

I see some ways to solve this:

> the problem is - every time the user enters a new activity, the music pauses for a second and then resumes, because for a second the current activity is paused

The first is you set a flag in the handler that start your new activity and
check in your onPause() method the value of de flag, if false, do nothing othewise mute de music.

```
public static boolean openOtherActivity = false;
```

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (!openOtherActivity) {
       MusicService.getMP().mute();
    }
}
```

You can use Preferences too if you preferrer

To resolve de onCreate() and onResume() problem, you can use the same logic
creates a flag for the services started and control when you needs unmute the music in anothers methods

```
public static boolean isServiceCreated = false; // In your activity that start the service
```

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    counter++;

    if (counter==1) {
        alliesSPEditor.putBoolean("isAllies", true);
        alliesSPEditor.commit();
        startService(new Intent(this,MusicService.class));
        isServiceCreated = true; // set the flag to true
    }
}

OnResume() method you can check if the service is started an create your logic
```